# How can I make a restriction for a parameter in my GLM

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to fit a GLM to some data. I wanna make a restriction for my parameters. I have 2 different restictions

1. $\beta_{1,1}=0$
2. $\sum_i^n\beta_i=0$

How can I tell R to do this. My GLM is $$glm(goals\sim Team+Oppo+Home-1,family = poisson(),data=season1617)$$

thanks

Comment: If $\beta_1$ is the term next to $goalsTeam$, then simply remove that column from the data...

Comment: I have edited my question. I want the first coefficent to be 0. The first team in the data is Arsenal, so i want TeamArsenal=0

Comment: If you are looking for a computational solution maybe you could try asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/